# Bootstrap toggle languages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, multilingual, jquery

I have a blog in two languages. i want to toggle between language A and B when clicking FlagA.png or FlagB.png. Every post contains at least two flags images. How can I do this using (bootstrap) Jquery? (context, I dont have a DB, in order to facilitate multi languages I want to make use of the toggle functions)

```
                    <div class="post">
                    <div class="post-content">
                        <div class="post-title"><a href="#"><b>title</b</a>                </div>
                        <a href="" class="languageA">
                                <img src="img/countryA.png" alt=""
                                    style="float: right;" /></a>
                        <a href="" class="languageB">
                                <img src="img/countryB.png"  alt="" style="float: right;
                                    padding-right: 10px;" /></a>
                        </br>
                        <div class="post-description">
                        <p>
                            post in language A
                        </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-description">

                        <p>
                            post in language B but now it is invisible, when pressed countryB image this becomes visible and post in language A not.
                        </p>
                        </div>
                    <p class="test"> test test test test test test test test test test test test</p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="post">
                   <!-- second post\-->
                   </div>
                   <!-- -->
                   <script type="text/jscript">
                  $(function() {
        $('.languageA').click(function () {
            $('.test').collapse({
                toggle: true
            })
        });
    });
                   });
                   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by the following method:

1. For all the content you want to toggle, you must give it the relevant language class. In the example below, I gave the title, country flag and post description a language class.
2. Use the click function to toggle the content with each language class when clicked. In this example, I limit the toggle to each post by using `$(this).parent` so you could read one post in one language and another in a different language.
3. Then you also implement a callback in each toggle to show the other language when the toggle has completed.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post-content">
      <div class="post-title languageA"><a href="#"><b>Title 1 in Language A</b></a></div>
      <div class="post-title languageB"><a href="#"><b>Title 1 in Language B</b></a></div>
        <a href="#" class="languageA">
          <img src="http://flags.redpixart.com/img/united_states_of_america_preview.gif" alt=""
          style="float: right;" /></a>
        <a href="#" class="languageB">
          <img src="http://flags.redpixart.com/img/spain_preview.gif"  alt="" style="float: right;
                                    padding-right: 10px;" /></a>
      <br/>
      <div class="post-description languageA">
        <p>
          Post 1 in language A
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="post-description languageB">
        <p>
          Post 1 in language B
        </p>
      </div>
      <p class="test"> test test test test test test test test test test test test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then the following JavaScript will toggle the language:

```
$(function() {
   // Hide Language B when the web page loads
   $('.languageB').hide();
   $('.languageA').click(function () {
       // find all content with .languageA under the div post-content and hide it
       $(this).parent().find('.languageA').fadeToggle('slow',function() {
             // find all content with .languageB under the div post-content and show it
             $(this).parent().find('.languageB').show();});
   });
   $('.languageB').click(function () {
       // find all content with .languageB under the div post-content and hide it
       $(this).parent().find('.languageB').fadeToggle('slow',function() {
             // find all content with .languageA under the div post-content and show it
             $(this).parent().find('.languageA').show(); });
   });
});
```

[JSFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/F2rFd/9/).

Comment: Sorry my requirements wasn't clear enough. I want to be able to set the default language PER post. When def lang in post 1 is spanish and I click on american flag I want to see the spanish text to fade away and english in the place of it. (the two flags must always be visible in the posts)
[link]http://jsfiddle.net/F2rFd/27/

Comment: For example: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/F2rFd/29/ 
in post one spanish text and all is invisible, when clicked on spanish flag english texts and all is invisible and spanish appears.
in post two the same but this time english is invisible, when clicked on english flag spanish disappears and english is visible.